# How to add wsu:Id attribute using zeep?

Tags: python, xml, soap, zeep

I have the following python code to set up header for a SOAP request:

```py
ebsheader = xsd.Element(
    '{http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/}EBS',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Attribute(
            'Id',xsd.String()
        ),
        xsd.Element(
            'SoftwareConformanceKey', xsd.String()
        ),
        xsd.Element(
            'AuditId', xsd.String()
        ),
    ])
)
headers = []
headers.append(ebsheader('id-1','software-key-here','unique-id'))
```

it produces the following xml:

```xml
<ns0:EBS xmlns:ns0="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/" Id="id-1">
  <SoftwareConformanceKey>software-key-here</SoftwareConformanceKey>
  <AuditId>unique-id</AuditId>
</ns0:EBS>
```

However, instead of `Id="id-1"` i need it to be `wsu:Id="id-1"`. Which parameter do I need to specify in the header to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a namespace, so for example

```
    xsd.Attribute(
        '{http://my-namespace}Id',xsd.String()
    ),
```

Comment: When I do this, i get this result: `<ns0:EBS xmlns:ns0="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/" ns0:Id="id-1">` I'm pretty new to xml, is it significant that it says `ns0:Id=...` instead of `wsu:Id=...` ?

Comment: The result should be the same, the ns0 / wsu is just a shorthand for the full namespace

Answer (score 2):

```
    settings = Settings(strict = False, xml_huge_tree = True)
    client = Client(wsdl_path, transport = self.transport, wsse = self.wsse,settings = settings)
    client.set_ns_prefix(ns_prefix,namespace)
    service = client.create_service('{{{}}}{}'.format(namespace, binding_name), xaddr)
```

client.set_ns_prefix(ns_prefix,namespace)  is the key point what you want.